# How to mark multiple elements without clicking in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="minute in hour.minutes track by $index">
    <td class="{{minute.class}}" ng-mousedown="setTdCol(hour, minute)" >&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`setTdCol` just changes `minute.class` causing the cell to change its background color.

My goal is to allow the user to mark multiple cells by pushing the mouse button **once** and then moving above the cells.

That is why I used `ng-mousedown` instead of `ng-click`, but still I have to release the mouse and click each column. What has to be changed?

Comment: You are only showing one column. Show enough relevant code to at least see how `setTdCol` works and more than one column. There is no way for us to reproduce this from what little code is shown

Comment: Also not at all clear what expected behavior is. You say you want them to select different cells and then say they have to clcik on different columns. What's the difference?

Comment: Its one cell per row, but multiple rows. What I want to achieve is: user klicjs onto first cell, moves mouse four cells down- releases button.: All four cells are marked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to build your logic together with `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseup`.

For example you can set a boolean variable `mouseDown` to true with `ng-mousedown` and set it to false with `ng-mouseup`. That way in your `ng-mouseover` function you can check if the mouse is down or up and mark the elements you go over. You can for example store them in an array and if the element exists in that array on hover - remove it. Or set them to active / inactive with boolean ... etc.

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: Seems to be a smart way to do this. Will try that.

Comment: If you need help I'm around :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to know when the mouse is down on the table and when it is, which minutes its hovering above. You can set a flag to indicate if the mouse is down on the table that will vary when the table's ng-mouseup and ng-mousedown are invoked, and give an ng-mouseover function to each cell that will check if this flag is true.

```
<table ng-mousedown="isDown = true" ng-mouseup="isDown = false">
  <tr ng-repeat="minute in hour.minutes track by $index">
    <td ng-style="minute.class" ng-mouseover='setTdCol(hour, minute)'>aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the example above, isDown is the flag. Now you just need to wrap setTdCol function in an if that checks if is down is true. just don't forget to initialize $scope.isDown in the controller

```
...
$scope.isDown = false;
  $scope.setTdCol = function(hour, minute) {
    if($scope.isDown) {
      ...
    }
  };
...
```